# Backup script doesn't walk the files in a folder

Tags: python, zip

I'm new to Python and one of my first projects is making a backup script.

Comment: This line doesn't look right: `newBase / os.path.basename(folder) + '_'` Are you sure that you copied your code correctly? That code should raise NameError on `newBase`.

Comment: The folder name you're backing up doesn't look right - is it really supposed to contain a hexadecimal escape sequence? Something like `\Users?6572\Downloads\`?